# Push Notification count (badge count) on android with Capacitor

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I'm using the capacitor/ionic framework and trying to get badge/notification count to appear on the app icon. From what I've read it should increment when a push is received and the app is backgrounded/closed.

Presently using emulator with the Pixel 2XL on API 28. The emulator is receiving notifications correctly.

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:key=$SERVER_KEY" -d "{
  \"to\" : \"$DEVICE_TOKEN\",
  \"notification\": {
    \"title\":\"FCM Message\",
    \"body\":\"This is an FCM Message\"
  },
  \"android\": {
    \"priority\": \"HIGH\",
    \"notification\": {
      \"channel_id\": \"$CHANNEL_ID\",
      \"notification_priority\": \"PRIORITY_MAX\",
      \"default_sound\": true,
      \"visibility\": \"PUBLIC\",
      \"notification_count\": 1
    }
  }
}" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

From what I read in documentation if you don't include `notification_count` then the icon should increment by `1` for each notification unless the app is opened. Neither is working for me?

```js
    // channel setup on device
    PushNotifications.createChannel({
      description: 'description string',
      id: channelName,
      name: channelName,
      importance: 5,
      visibility: 1,
    })
```

**Firebase Cloud Message Construction**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message

Comment: Firebase has not supported badge on Android. You can send firebase data-message, when received a message, read the badge and set programmatically.

Comment: @BrianHoang Would setting programmatically not require the app to be opened first? defeating the purpose of the count/alert.

Comment: Maybe I miss-understood, but I thought that if count was not set android would increment the count of notifications until the app was opened?
> https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#set_custom_notification_count _By default, each notification increments a number displayed on the long- press menu_

Comment: But what is not working? The badge or the auto increment? If it’s the badge, most android devices don’t support badges, the docs say “for launchers that support badging” because most don’t support it

Comment: @jcesarmobile you're comment was helpful thanks, I was indeed using an unsupported device.